# Stacking divs in a single page and moving between them

Tags: html, css

This graphic roughly represents what I am trying to do. The second rectangle in the top left represents the viewport. Which means that each div should cover the whole viewport and none of the other three should be visible.

[image: Stacking divs full page]

So I used this css:

```
body  {overflow : hidden;}

#page {width:200%;
       position : absolute;}

#page div {width: 50%;
       position:relative;
       height: 100%;}
```

Next, I put anchor tags in the divs so as to navigate between them. But it doesnt work. I get to the second div alright but I cant go to any other divs. I know this can be sloved by jquery but I would like to do this with pure HTML and CSS, using jquery only to animate the transition.

How do I do it?

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfzWg/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle on what you are talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/X4URc/3/

I used html:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='navbar'>
        <div align='center'> <a class='menu1 menu-item'>Item 1</a>
 <a class='menu2 menu-item'>Item 2</a>
 <a class='menu3 menu-item'>Item 3</a>
 <a class='menu4 menu-item'>Item 4</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
        <ul class='content-container'>
            <li class='contents content1'>Content 1</li>
            <li class='contents content2'>Content 2</li>
            <li class='contents content3'>Content 3</li>
            <li class='contents content4'>Content 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-item {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-item:hover {
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
.menu-item:not(.menu1) {
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.navbar {
    background: black;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 700px;
}
.container {
    background: white;
    width: 730px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content1 {
    margin-left: -40px;
}
.contents {
    padding-bottom: 400px;
    padding-right: 668px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
.contents:not(.content1) {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
body {
    background: #ccc;
}
.content {
    width: 730px;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content-container {
    width: 9999999px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.menu1').click(function(){
    $('.content1').css({'margin-left' : '-40px'});
});
$('.menu2').click(function(){
    $('.content1').css({'margin-left' : '-770px'});
});
$('.menu3').click(function(){
    $('.content1').css({'margin-left' : '-1500px'});
});
$('.menu4').click(function(){
    $('.content1').css({'margin-left' : '-2230px'});
});
// for more add -730px every time
//If you don't want animations change .animate() to .css()
```

Instead of having lots of divs, I used a  within a div with overflow hidden and then styled it display: inline;

Answer (score 0):

A good method for this might be ScrollTo
http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/